# Have I outgrown the shared hosting or I my scripts aren't optimized?

Tags: php, hosting

I currently have more than 1000 visits / day and hosting at 1and1 with PHP memory 30MB limit
I have a dynamic shopping guide with more than 5000 items and users enter to browse / search for items. I started getting "Internal Error 500" every now and then. Which are show more on days, and I don't notice them on others. 1and1 support say that I have outgrown the 30MB PHP limit. 
What do you think? Is that true? or they just want to sell me a more expensive hosting? I currently can't afford more than a shared host :(

I am using PHP / MySQL Javascript / My BB Forum / PHP thumbail (which I am now trying to switch with static thumbnails to ease the load a bit)
Advice is appreciated

Comment: Sounds possible... You'll have to find out which parts of your code break the limit. It's well possible you can help this by optimizing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to another hosting "Blue Host" and the errors stopped ever since. It seems they handle the resources in a different way: "CPU throttling". And they told me I can use their services till I feel the website is slow and I then should switch to VPS or dedicated server. 1and1 handle the overload on shared limits with error 500. This is not good!

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that disk space constraints are causing 500s, even with 5000 items over 30mb, that's roughly 6k per item - only probably if each item has an image.

When you reach your disk quota, most PHP frameworks will report an error themselves, rather than sending a bog standard 500 response, so the 30Mb limit is almost certainly not the problem. Your hosting company may have other limits they're imposing, but even 1000 visits a day shouldn't break the most draconian hosting thresholds. It's more likely that your hosting company are looking for an easy up-sell.

Give us a URL and maybe we can get a clearer picture, but it's more likely something is simply broken in your site's code. Of course, without any reference material, this is strictly a theory.

Comment: Seems like @Yasser is saying the limit is how much memory PHP can get -- 30 megabytes -- not disc space. Any host only offering 30 megs of disc space died off years ago.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but 30mb of RAM seems even less likely, given it's usually allocated in powers of 2. PHP would have to handle ten or so simultaneous hits to consume that much memory, and even then, Apache should just queue them, rather than serving 500s.

Comment: Yes sure, it's the memory usage, not the disk space of traffic quota. 1and1 said that my users consume the resources ending up with error 500 every while.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bumping up against 30 megabytes of PHP memory (if you are in fact talking about the php memory_limit setting, which it seems you are), then most likely some optimization could solve it. I usually only hit that kind of number if I'm processing large arrays and/or converting to PDF files, etc.  And then I usually figure out a way to drop the array size by using memcached or writing the PDF some other way or something like that.

Sometimes the easiest thing to do is to buy their upgrade. Throwing hardware at the problem can at least be a quick fix. If you are making money from your web site, any time you get a 500, you could be losing money so it might be wise financially for you. But, you didn't ask that question. :)

To determine how much memory your scripts are using, sprinkle https://www.php.net/memory_get_usage around at strategic spots to see (assuming you don't have a profiler that can handle this better).

Comment: throwing memory_get_usage() helps with optimizing the scripts, but doesn't tell me the whole usage. I still don't understand why I have error 500 more on certain days, and on other days it's not. It even happens some time just 1 shot.. on other times, it persists for 10 seconds! I don't know if the hosting are honest :(